# How to get Computers list from active directory by Wmi in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, active-directory, ldap, wmi

I have one window active directory and I have connected my computer to active directory for accessing the computers which is connected.

I have written below python code For connecting,

```
import wmi
try:
    connection = wmi.WMI(ip, user=username, password=password)
    print "connection is establised"
    for users in connection.Win32_SystemUsers():
        print users
except:
    print "connection failed"
```

Above code is showing all users list but i don't know how to get computers list with wmi win32 class.

Now problem is I want computer list which is in active directory using python. Anyone help me.

**or**

I found another method for connecting, that is ldap but here same problem is occuring. i am not able to find or access computer list.

I have used below code for connecting and showing user list

```
l = ldap.initialize("ldap://192.168.1.40")
try:
    l.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
    l.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)

    bind = l.simple_bind_s("administrator@example.com", "example@123")

    base = "dc=example, dc=com"
    criteria = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=*))"
    attributes = ['displayName', 'company']
    result = l.search_s(base, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, criteria, attributes)

    results = [entry for dn, entry in result if isinstance(entry, dict)]
    print results
finally:
    l.unbind()
```

Now how to get computer's list

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nobody has answer of this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to search for computer why do you search for users?

```
criteria = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=*))"
```

Try this:

```
criteria = "(&(objectClass=computer))"
```

Comment: Thanks I got computers list but how to access all computer's drive, actually i want to read all file content of computer's drive.

Comment: Please open a new question where you state what you have and what you want to achieve, this is nothing to discuss in comments.